# Create an Attendance view from one column timesheet (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have this data of attendance from SQL Server that I must split into 2 columns (in and out).

Here is an example:

[The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgCB1.png)

And here is the result that I want

[image]

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DATETIME] [datetime] NULL,
    [Flag] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES ('ID-1', '2019-03-13 09:48:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-13 09:48:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-13 18:11:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-13 18:11:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 02:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 09:54:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 09:54:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 09:54:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 22:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 22:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-14 22:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 13:55:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 13:55:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 13:55:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 13:55:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 13:55:00.000', '2'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 22:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 22:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 22:00:00.000', '3'),
       ('ID-1', '2019-03-15 22:00:00.000', '3')
```

**Note:**

1. The flag 2 means IN and 3 means OUT.
2. There can be more than one check in and check out so we must take the first in and last out.
3. There can be overtime so sometimes we must check the check out data from the next day.

How can I do this?

Comment: Anything that you've try?

Comment: Well i've try something with joins but i can't get it right
I'm new in this so i can't think any other way.... 
I'm sorry if i can't support you with anything except the picture....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use images/image links, as it makes us unable to copy-paste them. The best is to include CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO queries for your tabls

Comment: Okay i will add the CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try a left join from Ins to outs, and find the earliest out time after that in-time.

sample below (untested):

```
WITH ins
AS ( SELECT *
     FROM   table1
     WHERE  Flag = 2 )
    ,outs
AS ( SELECT *
     FROM   table1
     WHERE  Flag = 3 )
SELECT   i.ID
        ,i.DATETIME InTime
        ,MIN(o.DATETIME) OutTime
FROM     ins i
         LEFT JOIN outs o ON o.ID = i.ID AND o.DATETIME > i.DATETIME -- out must be later than in
GROUP BY i.ID
        ,i.DATETIME
        ,i.Flag;
```

Comment: Well it worked but it can't get the overtime data if the overtime goes until next date

Comment: @YandityaEkaputra Well that's the problem with using a poorly designed schema. You have no obvious way to identify a "work period" when that period crosses a day boundary. Since you're new to this, you should ask your teammates, team leader, or supervisor for help. The first thing to do is to identify a simple set of sample data that contains a "normal" set of rows that occur within a single day and a set of rows that crosses a day boundary. There might be some simplifying assumptions you can make.

Comment: The other problem is i'm the only developer here.

Comment: @YandityaEkaputra, i am not sure what you meant by "the overtime data if the overtime goes until next date" -- did you mean the in and out must be within the same day (which implies the out could be null if there is no checkout on the same day)?  if so, we just need to tweak the left join condition to also make sure the in and out are in the same day...